# Dynamically added checkbox not model binding to IList

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, checkbox, model-binding

I have a view that spits out a table for an `IList<T>`, where `T` is like this:

```
public class ModelType
{
    public int EntityId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool RequiresComment { get; set; }
}
```

The Razor code (truncated for brevity):

```
@model IList<ModelType>
<table id="theTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Requires Comment</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @for(var i = 0;i < Model.Count;i++)
        {
            <tr>
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].EntityId)
                <td>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[i].Description)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m[i].RequiresComment)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
<input type="button" id="addRowButton" value="Add Row" />
<input type="submit" value="Save" />
```

Then, I have some jQuery to handle the "Add Row" click event:

```
$("#addRowButton").click(function(){
    var index = $("#theTable tbody tr").length;
    var newRow = '<tr><input type="hidden" name="[' + index + '].EntityId" value="0" />' + 
        '<td><input type="text" name="[' + index + '].Description" style="width: 98%" /></td>' + 
        '<td style="text-align: center;"><input type="checkbox" name="[' + index + '].RequiresComment" />' +
        '<input name="[' + index + '].RequiresComment" type="hidden" value="false" /></td></tr>';
    $("#theTable tbody tr:last").after(newRow);
});
```

The table row gets added perfectly, and everything looks good (so far as I can tell) when I Fiddle the POST.  But for some reason, if a new row is added and the "RequiresComment" field is checked on the newly added row, the model binder still comes through with a `RequiresComment` value of `false`.

Before everyone references [Phil Haack's famous collection model binding post](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx) or points me at other questions talking about model binding dynamically generated HTML elements, let me say that I have done this several times successfully with other types of `<input />` elements.  It's just the `checkbox` that doesn't seem to work.  I've tried adding an ID to the element, messed around with adding an `<input type="hidden" name="[index].RequiresComment" value="false" />` as Fiddler shows for every posted field that was loaded from the first view call, but I can't get new rows that are actually checked to come through as `true` to the model binder.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your generated checkbox is missing the value parameter, it should be set to "true" in your case. As far as I remember, ob submit only checked checkbox values are submitted, for that reason MVC alsways creates a hidden field to make sure the value for an unchecked checkbox is always submitted, because the value could also be a text or a number.

Comment: @developer10214, ah ha, yep, that's it.  Adding value=true works.  You should answer this question so I can upvote and accept.

Comment: I put my comment as an answer. I'm glad to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your generated checkbox is missing the `value` parameter, it should be set to `true` in your case.

As far as I remember, on submit only checked checkbox values are submitted. For that reason MVC always creates a hidden field to make sure, the value for an unchecked checkbox is always submitted. Although a checkbox is often used for a boolean value, the value could also be a text or a number.